# WPF simulate Application.Activated event

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to use `Application.Activated` event in WPF but I have no Application object or Windows neither. 
Can other elements use this event or Is there a chance to simulate activated event?

Comment: There is also a [Window.Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.activated.aspx) event.

Comment: I know but my project starts with an `UserControl`.

Comment: And none of Initialized, Loaded, GotKeyboardFocus etc. is sufficent?

Comment: Nope. My project can be executed by a `c++` application. When I inspect the application with `Snoop` the root of the tree is an UserControl. I tried to listen `WndProc` messages but i can not catch `WM_ACTIVATE` message.